# Using joptionpane to exit the program

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a gui java program that count the number of files (if any) in a folder and store their names in an array for processing. In the case when no files are available to process, I want to display a joptionpane with the message " No files are available to process. Please click the exit button to exit the system ".

How can I exit the system when the user click the button of the joptionpane?
Something like

```
if (array.length == 0){
    JOptionPane.show .......
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the return value of the `JOptionPane` as such:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(window,
        "Are you sure you want to quit?",
        "Confirm Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) System.exit(0);
```

Comment: It works but ideally I would like only one button i.e. OK or Exit instead of three options (yes, no and cancel).

Comment: Look at the API documentation for ```JOptionPane``` and you will see you can change that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David for your help. The following is what I was looking for.

```
        if (filesToCompileArray.length == 0){

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "No failure found in the SUT and no files are generated to process further",
                "Confirm Quit", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        if (result == 0) System.exit(0);

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the 0 when checking the result. Instead, use one of the defined ```JOptionPane``` integer options as shown in my answer.

Comment: `Thanks David for your help` Then you should "accept" David's answer.